# The -var and -var-file options cannot be used when applying a saved plan file

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using Gitlab terraform & the yaml file is as below for deploy stage,

```
build:
  extends: .terraform:build
  script:
    - cd "${TF_ROOT}"
    - gitlab-terraform plan --var-file=local.tfvars --var-file=common.tfvars
    - gitlab-terraform plan-json --var-file=local.tfvars --var-file=common.tfvars
```

```
deploy:
  extends: .terraform:deploy
  script:
    - cd "${TF_ROOT}"
    - gitlab-terraform apply --var-file=local.tfvars --var-file=common.tfvars
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
```

First time it deployed perfectly, However my Gitlab log shows the following error now for the second time,

│ **Error: Can't set variables when applying a saved plan**

The -var and -var-file options cannot be used when applying a saved plan

file, because a saved plan includes the variable values that were set when

it was created.

**ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1**

I am looking through the internet but no help till now.

Can someone please suggest me the terraform command I should use to avoid this error ?

Comment: I think you should only run `terraform apply <saved plan file name>`.

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, But without passing the variables it would give the error. Also what do you mean by <saved plan file name>, how do you add it in gitlab-ci.yaml file, out state files are stored in GCP Buckets

Comment: I have added the plan/build stage code as well in above question. In plan stage it executes & shows everything correctly but when it comes to deploy/apply stage it fails

Comment: What does `plan-json` do?

Comment: @MarkoE This JSON is used to create a GitLab Terraform Report artifact. The Terraform report obtains a Terraform tfplan.json file.https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/mr_integration.html

Comment: Ok, so you need a way to get that output file. The doc you sent shows you how to save it. You then need to use it in the apply step. That would be the `<saved plan file name>` reference.

Comment: Thank you @MarkoE, I am trying to understand this a bit now. yes I will try this & also its downloading the build artifacts, may be only terraform apply may work. Thank you once again

Comment: @MarkoE, thanks. running only "gitlab-terraform apply" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as OP and I'm just posting their solution from a comment they made.

Remove any `-var-file` arguments after [`gitlab-terraform apply`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/-/blob/master/src/bin/gitlab-terraform.sh) to fix the error. Here's an example of a working job:

```
deploy:
  extends: .terraform:deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - gitlab-terraform apply
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: start
```

PS The whole `script` section can be left out in the example above since it the same as in the [base job](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the [`TF_CLI_ARGS` variable](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables#tf_cli_args-and-tf_cli_args_name) in your CI environment (i.e. your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file), will make terraform commands run in that environment with those args included.

So for example, setting the below variables in your pipeline file..

```
variables: 
  TF_CLI_ARGS: "-var-file=myvars.tfvars"
  TF_CLI_ARGS_plan: "-var-file=plan.tfvars"
```

..will make sure that all terraform commands are executed with `-var-file=myvars.tfvars` appended, and the `terraform plan` command will run with `-var-file=myvars.tfvars -var-file=plan.tfvars` appended.

As the `gitlab-terraform` tool is just a [wrapper](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/-/blob/master/src/bin/gitlab-terraform.sh) around existing terraform commands, setting this variable should work with that lib.